# How do I place a View belonging to a Plugin in regular View (CakePHP Howto)

Tags: php, templates, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I would like to get some input regarding the feasibility of the following scenario/design pattern:

I would like to insert a `View` from a Category Plugin (`/category/categories/tree`) into one of my application Views (`/posts/edit/3`) as if it is an CakePHP element.
The inserted `View` has a high level of functionality (sorting, adding, deleting, etc...) and therefore simply calling `echo $this->element();` does not seem appropriate to me. That 'feels' more like a practice appropriate in situations where 'snippet'/lower level functionality is needed.

My question: is this possible in CakePHP, if so: how to do this? (just a rough outline of the way to go would suffice)
My first idea is to call an `element` from the plugin and use `$this->requestAction();` from the element.
But as I said earlier is my association with elements one of little functionality/snippet. Using a controller method and its `View` 'feels' more appropriate. But I don't know how to 'call' a View within a View.

Main reason why I would want this:
full Controller functionality.

- activate helpers based on Plugin requirements (this should be of no concern to the posts-controller)
- beforeFilter and beforeRender of Plugin might be of use. For example: `$this->set('modelName', $this->modelClass);`

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using [view blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#view-blocks). AFAIK, they are generally designed to help solve more complex view construction, like the problem you are considering here.

Or call a [plugin element directly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#requesting-elements-from-a-plugin).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know a bout blocks yet. Still the suggestions you make does not include full Controller goodies (beforeFilter, helpers etc...) and those are key to me, but maybe not outlined sufficiently. I'll rephrase my question a bit.